# Working with iPhone Addressbook

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am building a contacts back up app for iPhone.I need help in following problem. Please give me some reference or examples.
How can i save all address book contacts to a file? Can i create my own file and then save all contacts in it?
After that i want to upload this file to a sever.